# no viable alternative parsing macro and override

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Using this https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/cpp antlr grammar Im trying to parse C++ code. Below is the same visitor class I'm using, I don't have much visitor function implemented,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <antlr4-runtime.h>

#include "parser/CPP14Lexer.h"
#include "parser/CPP14BaseVisitor.h"
#include "parser/CPP14Parser.h"
#include "parser/CPP14Visitor.h"


class TREEVisitor : public CPP14BaseVisitor {
    public:
        virtual antlrcpp::Any TREEVisitor::visitFunctionBody(
            CPP14Parser::FunctionBodyContext *ctx) override
        {
            std::cout << ctx->getText() << std::endl;
            return visitChildren(ctx);
        }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    std::ifstream stream;
    stream.open(argv[1]);
    antlr4::ANTLRInputStream input(stream);
    CPP14Lexer lexer(&input);
    antlr4::CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);
    CPP14Parser parser(&tokens);
    antlr4::tree::ParseTree *tree = parser.translationunit();

    // Visitor
    auto *visitor = new TREEVisitor();
    visitor->visit(tree);

    return 0;
}
```

Im trying to parse the following C++ code,

```
#include <atomic>

#define RUN_ONCE                                       \
    for (static std::atomic<int> _run_already_(false); \
         !_run_already_.fetch_or(true);)               \

void foo()
{
    RUN_ONCE
    {
        printf("Hello only once!\n");
        /* Other statements follow */
    }
}
```

and I get the following message,

```
line 11:36 no viable alternative at input 'voidfoo(){RUN_ONCE{printf("Hello only once!\n");'
line 14:0 extraneous input '}' expecting <EOF>
```

Something is wrong with `RUN_ONCE{}` but Im not sure how I can solve this issue?

I have the same problem when I have for example a variable called override!

```
void foo()
{
    std::string override;
}
```

I get the following message,

```
line 9:16 no viable alternative at input 'voidfoo(){std::stringoverride'
line 9:24 mismatched input ';' expecting {'try', '{', '=', ':'}
line 10:0 extraneous input '}' expecting <EOF>
```

I don't mind ignoring `override` and don't see it as a C++ keyword anymore. I'm not sure how I should modify my grammars.

I really appreciate your answers to solve this issue.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

The C++ grammar you're using doesn't really support macros¹. It just skips lines starting with `#` during lexing and then assumes that the rest of the source is syntactically valid without any macro processing. That is clearly not the case in your code and that's why it doesn't work.

You'll either need to pass your code through an existing preprocessor before passing it to your parser or implement your own preprocessor.

Your second issue is due to the fact that the grammar treats `override` as a keyword when it should be a contextual keyword, i.e. it should still be allowed as an identifier. You can fix that by creating a non-terminal for identifiers that matches contextual keywords as well as `Identifier`s and then use that everywhere where `Identifier` is currently used.

---

¹ Which is to be expected. You can't really parse un-preprocessed C or C++ with a single grammar.

Comment: How can I do preprocess part?

Comment: @Alex Using an existing preprocessor or creating your own? To use an existing one, you can either just say that source files should be preprocessed before being passed to your application, i.e. leave it to the user to call on it `gcc -E` before calling your program; or you could invoke it yourself and capture the output in a string, which you then pass to your parser.

Comment: If you want to build one yourself, it's a lot more complicated. For that you should look at what the C standard says about preprocessing, but basically you'll want to create a lexer and parser for the preprocessing syntax and have the preprocessor produce a preprocessed token stream, which you can then use as the input of your C++ parser.

Comment: I think preprocessor is not an option for me, because most of the code I parsing are not complete and I don't have all the dependencies!
Is there any alternative for this other than preprocessing?
Is there anyway I can have a visitor the defines?
I'm also not sure how to implement what you suggested to solve the problem with `override`?

Thanks

Comment: @Alex There's no way you can correctly parse non-preprocessed C++ if you don't have access to the included headers. What if the relevant defines are in such a header? Or what if the included file itself is needed to make the current file syntactially valid (less common case admittedly). That said, `clang -E` can handle missing header files, so in cases where all defines necessary for correct parsing are visible to you, that should work fine.

Comment: As for `override`: `id: Identifier | Override | OtherContextualKeywordsGoHere;` and then use `id` instead of `Identifier` everywhere.

Comment: Great thanks. I have another issue which I think it could be related so I will ask it here. In C++ we can have like `stringstream << "A" "B";` without having `<<` between "A" and "B". Also when you are invoking a macro you are not obligated to have `;` at the end of the line!
which make ANTLR to give me some error! How I can fix those?

Thanks

Comment: @Alex Merging adjacent string literals is another thing that's handled by the preprocessor, so it's not handled in the ANTLR grammar. That said, changing the all uses of `StringLiteral` to allow one or more `StringLiteral`s instead should solve this without involving a preprocessor. Whether you need a semicolon after a macro call or not entirely depends on the definition of the macro. So again that's not something that the parser can decide unless the macros are expanded before the code is fed into the parser.

Comment: Any tip on how I should modify `StringLiteral`?. Is it possible to address the problem macro without semicolon by modifying the grammars?

Thanks

Comment: @Alex You shouldn't change `StringLiteral`, you should change all uses of it (or at least all where multiple string literals are allowed) to allow one or more string literals (using the appropriate repetition operator). As I said earlier, it is not possible to properly handle macros during parsing - especially not if the macros expand to something other than full expressions or are used as anything other than full expressions. For that you'll need a preprocessing phase in some shape or form.